# DBUS - Is it possible to have 2 instance of session bus or something similar?

Tags: dbus

I am facing some weird requirement with DBus based implementation. I would like to know if this is possible to have 2 instance of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS` or anything similar to this.

Well, the reason why I am looking for this typical requirement is my processes (nodes on bus) are duplicated (i.e having 1+ instance) and they all have registered for the same signals. 
For example, Node-A and Node-B both emit `SIGNAL-1` and Node-X and Node-Y both would like to receive `SIGNAL-1` (they have registered for `SIGNAL-1` by `dbus_add_match()` call).

As it stands now, when the `SIGNAL-1` is emitted, the dbus daemon delivers it to both Node-X and Node-Y.

My requirement is Node-A's `SIGNAL-`1 should be received by Node-X and Node-B's `SIGNAL-1` should be received by Node-B

What I have tried / analysed :
1. `dbus_connection_open_private()` - Not much help, not sure on usage part as limited documentation is available.
2. `dbus_bus_get_private()` - not relevant in this scenario.
3. Thinking of replication the daemon - Too complicated and not easy to achieve.
4. Possibility of using `DBUS_XYX_BU`S instead of `DBUS_SESSION_BU`S (with respective changes) - again too complicated and not sure on dependencies.

I would like to know your views on this, any help / directions / heads up will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: So node A's SIGNAL-1 is to be received by node X *and not node Y*? Is that the requirement? My understanding is that the session bus is a per login session bus so if there was another session active then there would be an additional corresponding session bus, but I'm no dbus expert. Could you use dbus messages addressed to where they need to go instead of signals?